# Mesh is behaving weird

Tags: texturing, vertices, normals

my mesh is doing some weird stuff. I tried to make a logo 3d and had a Logo reference image which I build on. I started with one vertex and CTRL + Right Clicked my way through to end up with the Logo. Now the problem is that my mesh is doing some weird stuff and is pulling to the starting vertex.
[image]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Hope you can help.

Cheers, Tobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh is shaded smooth more than likely. Go into the object menu, and set it to shade flat, or go into the mesh data tab of the properties editor, and enable auto smooth.

Comment: LEGEND, thanks solved the problem!

Comment: This answer is short, direct and correct, but I feel like it's a good opportunity to learn about Ngons (this knowledge could be useful in future projects, especially if you intend to deform your object):

Comment: In 3D software every face is a triangle. Faces that appear to be other shapes are actually made up of several triangles. So working with Ngons (shapes with more than 4 sides) is not recommended. When you have an Ngon you leave it to the software to decide how to arrange the triangles to make up the shape, and that leads to bad topology (like the triangles converging to a single vertex in your case). When you shade smooth the software tries to avarage the normals of the faces to make the shading smooth, but when the topology is bad it leads to artifacts like the ones you have in your mesh.

Comment: When the Ngon is completely flat (like in your case) the artifacts can be removed by changing the smoothing groups (which is done automatically when you enable auto smooth).
But if you intend to add more details to the mesh or deform it in any way (like bending, twisting, using an armature deform, etc), you will have to do some retopologizing by cutting the Ngons into smaller shapes with less sides (ideally each face should have no more than 4 sides), that way you have greater control of how the triangulation is being made and avoid smoothing artifacts and unwanted deformation.

Comment: @Squizy t Y Jesus! 